# Integral in direct calculation of anomalies

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, quantum-anomalies

I am trying to follow Weinberg's triangle diagram calculations in section 22.3 of volume II of *The Quantum Theory of Fields*.  He reduces the calculation to evaluating the integral
\begin{equation}
\tag{22.3.16}
I_{\kappa\lambda}(k, c, d) = \int d^{4}p\, \left[f_{\kappa\lambda}(p + k, c, d) - f_{\kappa\lambda}(p, c, d)\right]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\tag{22.3.17}
f_{\kappa\lambda}(p, c, d) = \frac{(p + c)_{\kappa}(p + d)_{\lambda}}{[(p + c)^{2} - i\epsilon][(p + d)^{2} - i\epsilon]}.
\end{equation}
where $c^{\mu}$ and $d^{\mu}$ are arbitrary constant four-vectors.  Since $f$ is quadratically divergent, we can't shift the variable of integration to make it vanish.  Instead, we Taylor expand $f_{\kappa\lambda}$ and appeal to Stokes' theorem to write
\begin{equation}
\tag{22.3.18}
I_{\kappa\lambda}(k, c, d)
= 
k^{\mu}\int d^{4}p\, \frac{\partial f_{\kappa\lambda}(p, c, d)}{\partial p^{\mu}}
+
\frac{1}{2}k^{\mu}k^{\nu}\int d^{4}p\, \frac{\partial^{2} f_{\kappa\lambda}(p, c, d)}{\partial p^{\mu}\, \partial p^{\nu}}
\end{equation}
Weinberg then says that a straightforward calculation gives
\begin{equation}
\tag{22.3.19}
I_{\kappa\lambda}(k, c, d)
=
\tfrac{1}{6}i\pi^{2}\left[
2k_{\lambda}c_{\kappa}
+
2k_{\kappa}d_{\lambda}
-
k_{\lambda}d_{\kappa}
-
k_{\kappa}c_{\lambda}
-
\eta_{\kappa\lambda} k \cdot (k + c + d)
\right]
\end{equation}
However, I can't reproduce this result, despite trying a couple different ways.

Any guidance would be helpful, but here is a specific question: how do you derive the part of $I_{\kappa\lambda}$ that's quadratic in $k$?  This has to come from the second term in (22.3.18).  One way to evaluate this term gives (writing $(\dots)$ around indices for symmetrization)
$$
\begin{align}
\int d^{4}p\, \frac{\partial^{2} f_{\kappa\lambda}}{\partial k^{\mu}\, \partial k^{\nu}}
&=
i
\lim_{p \to \infty}\int d\Omega_{4}\, 
p^{2}p_{\mu}\frac{\partial f_{\kappa\lambda}}{\partial k^{\nu}}
\\&=
2i \lim_{p \to\infty} \int dx\, dy\, d\Omega_{4}\, \delta(x + y - 1)\,
\frac{
p^{2}p_{\mu}p_{(\kappa}\eta_{\lambda)\nu}
}{[p^{2} + xy(c - d)^{2}]^{2}}
\\&\phantom{=}
-
8i
\lim_{p \to\infty} \int dx\, dy\, d\Omega_{4}\, \delta(x + y - 1)\, x
\frac{
p^{2}p_{\mu}p_{\nu}p_{\kappa}p_{\lambda}
}{[p^{2} + xy(c - d)^{2}]^{3}}
\\&=
\tfrac{1}{3}i\pi^{2}\eta_{\mu(\rho}\eta_{\sigma)\nu}
-
\tfrac{1}{3}i\pi^{2}\eta_{\mu\rho}\eta_{\sigma\nu}
\end{align}
$$
by Wick rotating and applying Stokes' theorem, then introducing Feynman parameters, shifting the limit variable and dropping sub-leading terms, and then taking the angular average to replace $2n$-fold products of $p$ with $n$-fold products of $\eta$.  Contracting this with $k$ gives
$$
\tag{$\star$}
\tfrac{1}{6}i\pi^{2}k_{\kappa}k_{\lambda}
-
\tfrac{1}{6}i\pi^{2}\eta_{\kappa\lambda}k^{2}
$$
The second term in ($\star$) is just what we want, matching the quadratic part of (22.3.19).  But the first term in ($\star$) doesn't appear in (22.3.19), so something's gone wrong.  The $1/6$ on the first term in ($\star$) is $\frac{1}{2} \times (1 - \frac{2}{3})$, where the $1/2$ is from the Taylor expansion, the $1$ is from the $2i$ integral and the $2/3$ is from the $8i$ integral.  So everything would work out correctly if we multiplied the $2i$ integral by $2/3$.  But I can't see any justification for doing that.